# jar decompiler freezes on some jars (Tried Procyon, JD-cmd and CFR)

Tags: java, jar, decompiler

I am trying to decompile some jar files. I tried Procyon, JD-cmd and CFR so far.

They are all doing well most of the jars but they freeze and do nothing on some jars. And these jars are different for Procyon, JD and CFR. (Procyon freezes on 2nd but JD freezes on 4th etc.)

The interesting part is, when I kill the process, they stop freezing and finish their job??

I am using them from inside a small java program as follows:

```
ExecuteCommand cmd = new ExecuteCommand();

cmd.executeCommand("java -jar " + cfrPath + " " + jarPath + " --outputdir " + unzip);
cmd.executeCommand("java -jar " + jdPath + " -od " + unzip + " " + jarPath);    
cmd.executeCommand("java -jar " + procyonPath + " -jar " + jarPath + " -o " + unzip);
```

And the ExecuteCommand.java class is:

```
public class ExecuteCommand {

    public void executeCommand(String command) {
         String s = null;

         try {

            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

            BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new 
                 InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

            BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new 
                 InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));

            while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(s);
            }

            while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(s);
            }

        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }   
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure they're actually frozen, or just taking a long time?

Comment: I am pretty sure

Comment: Procyon author here.  If you decompile from the command line, you should be able to see what class it's hanging on.  The most likely explanations that spring to mind are (1) generic type inference is getting caught in some kind of deep or infinite loop related to recursive type parameters; or (2) one of the classes has an extremely large method with complex control flow, possibly engineered specifically to trip up decompilers.  You're welcome to contact me directly and arrange a way to get me a copy of the jar so I can take a look myself.  My contact info is on the Procyon BitBucket site.

Comment: I am sending an email now thank you!

Comment: If you send me the jar, I can try Krakatau with it and see whether Krakatau gets stuck and if so, where and why.

Answer (score 1):

I received the jars you sent.  I was able to decompile two of them successfully; the third jar (the smallest one) appears to be empty.

What version of Procyon are you using?  On my workstation, both the latest release (v0.5.30) and the current development branch decompile the first two jars without hanging, though some classes do fail to decompile properly.  Note, however, that both took a while to fully decompile: one took about 48 seconds, and the other took 2 minutes, 30 seconds on my 2013-era Core i7.

I did notice a few classes that might have taken a very long time to decompile with **older** versions of Procyon, back when there was a runaway complexity bug related to binary operators.  Check your version number and grab the latest release if you're out of date.

On a side note, Procyon does not do a very good job with classes that have been run through tools like dex2jar.  Even in the best cases, you should exercise a healthy level of skepticism toward any code produced by a decompiler.  For code that has been transformed by dex2jar, you should be downright suspicious of the output.

Comment: I am using 0.5.30 too. It still freezes on a class. I wait almost 1 hour. If you managed to decompile it, then the problem is "executing the Procyon from inside a java program". And I dont know what is the wrong part of my code. At least, how can I skip if Procyon freezes on a class? How can I skip to the next class?

Comment: If I had to guess, maybe it's your max heap size?  I didn't specify an override for my own test, but you could try bumping the max heap size, e.g. running with `-Xmx2g` for 2GB.  The argument would be to `java` (the JVM), not to Procyon, so you could insert it before `-jar [procyon jar path]`.  I should note that I don't have the Android SDK or any other Android frameworks in my classpath, which *might* make a difference (Procyon loads and inspects referenced classes for type information like generics).

Comment: It freezes always as this: Decompiling android/support/v4/util/MapCollections$ArrayIterator...

Can you please try to run procyon with Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command) ?